# Call function after Jquery Modal Popup opens

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a Jquery autocomplete, when user selects the available value from input box. if selected value matches i want to open a modal dialog (which has some message and busy icon) till the time operation is happening on page. So far i have following code. and it opens Modal dialog box but does not execute my code within.

```
ctrl.keydown(function (event) {
                if(event.type=="keydown"){  
                    ctrl.autocomplete({
                        source: getSource,
                        delay: 200,
                        change: function (event, ui) {
 var source = $(this).val();
                            var temp = $(".ui-autocomplete li").map(function () { return $(this).text() }).get(); 
                            var found = $.inArray(source, temp);
if (found < 0) {
                                $(this).val(''); //this clears out the field if non-existing value in <select><options> is typed.
                            }else{
 $('#Dlgloading').on('dialogopen', function (e) {
alert("hello world");
//my code.....
});
                            }
                            
}
```

**EDIT**
I had to use Settimeout option to execute my function. first i open dialog and then after 3 seconds i start executing function.

Comment: When you say "but does not execute my code within."  which block are you referring to ? Are you saying that the alert doesn't execute when your modal opens up?

Comment: yes... actually instead of alert there are multiple for loop and API calls

Comment: Could you let me know where exactly are you triggering the modal to open ? Please paste the entire code, if possible..   Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#dialog-message').dialog("open");
setTimeout(function(){
//My Function code
 },3000);
```

May be very simple answer but other options like .load(href,function()) or open did not work for me